# Dynamically Alter Node Edit Tab Link

Tags: nodes, routes

I would like to all the href of the edit tab link on several nodes.

IOW: instead of

example.com/node/%/edit

I would like to substitute my dynamically created link

example.com/products/$myproductid/edit

My first stab at this (just to see if I understood the wild cards):

```
function jch_utilities_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/edit']['title'] = '1234';
}
```

...and this fires, BUT I don't understand how to pass the URL I want dynamically to it.

What I want to do is pass a variable from the node (a field variable) to that link.

I see that there is a page callback member of the array but that seems to call the node_edit page... which is over my head. I can't find a simple clear example of how to do this without a -lot- of study.

Is there no way to simply -force- a link href as one could do with jQuery?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module call [Sub Path Auto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto)

here is a [help video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFfrl8QUy_8) with an example that should work for you.

Module description :

> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites
>   the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased
>   URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking
>   a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is
>   based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the
>   Pathauto module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed
>   internal non-administrative URLs.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pass a -variable- from the node to the callback function which builds the link.

Comment: Ok, what variable are you trying to pass where ? You might be able to use the module mentioned above and a hook_form_alter() or something.